# Python BeautifulSoup HTML parse

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Hi guys i have question about parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup
My question is how to parse this html:

```
<div class="time_table show_today" id="monday_schedule">
          <h3>January 20, 2014</h3>
                        <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Time</th>
                  <th>Program</th>
                </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td class="time_part"> 0:00 </td>
                      <td class="show_content">
                        <h4>
                          First Up
                        </h4>
                        <p>
                          Bloomberg Television&#39;s award winning morning show takes a look at market openings in Asia and analyzes all the breaking news stories essential for your business day ahead.                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td class="time_part"> 2:00 </td>
                      <td class="show_content">
                        <h4>
                          On the Move with Rishaad Salamat
                        </h4>
                        <p>
                          Rishaad Salamat brings you comprehensive coverage of market openings from Asia and live reporting on the stories most impacting business around the globe.                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td class="time_part"> 4:00 </td>
                      <td class="show_content">
                        <h4>
                          Asia Edge
                        </h4>
                        <p>
                          Get to the bottom of the days major issues influencing business decisions with Rishaad Salamat. Asia Edge gives viewers a deeper perspective through extended interviews with the region&#39;s newsmakers as well as fast-paced panel discussions featuring Bloomberg&#39;s market reporters, business experts and influential guests. Stay ahead of the business day with Asia Edge.                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

My code looks like:

```
url = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/tv/schedule/europe/'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

for line in soup.findAll('div',{'td','h4','p'}):
    print line
```

What I'm doing wrong in code, some advice would be great.
The problem is when  `<h3>January 20, 2014</h3`
is going for about week and he only take one but loop can't do anything to print it in every line with all others tags.

Comment: I can't understand your last sentence at all. What do you want the output to be, for the given HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `{'td','h4','p'}` as a second argument. That's a `set`, and not a `dict` (as you may be thinking it is).

If you want to obtain the date, a simple `soup.find('h3')` should be good here:

```
>>> print soup.find('h3')
<h3>January 20, 2014</h3>
>>> print soup.find('h3').text
January 20, 2014
```

Comment: Yea that is good, but if you take date in for loop, it wont parse all tags from html